# passing Parameterized input using Mockitos

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am using Mockito for unit testing. I am wondering if its possible to send Parametrized input parameters with as in Junit testing
e.g

```
@InjectMocks
MockClass mockClass = new MockClass();

@Test
public void mockTestMethod()
    {
    mockClass.testMethod(stringInput); 
// here I want to pass a list of String inputs 
// this is possible in Junit through Parameterized.class.. 
// wondering if its can be done in Mockito
    }
```

Comment: can you provide an example to show how you want to use Mockito in your unit test ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In JUnit, [Parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) use [a special runner](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.java) that ensure that the test is instantiated multiple times, so each test method is called multiple times. Mockito is a tool for writing specific unit tests, so there is no built-in ability to run the same test multiple times with different Mockito expectations.

If you want your test conditions to change, your best bet is to do one of the following:

- Parameterize your test using JUnit, with a parameter for the mock inputs you want;
- Run a loop of different parameters in your test, which unfortunately avoids the "test one thing per method" philosophy
- Extract a method that actually performs the test, and create a new `@Test` method for each mock you want.

Note that there's no prohibition on using mock objects as `@Parameterized` test parameters. If you're looking to parameterize based on mocks, you can do that, possibly creating the mock and setting the expectations in a static method on the test.

---

**Note about runners**: This [Parameterized test runner](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.java) conflicts with Mockito's [MockitoJUnitRunner](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html): Each test class can only have one runner. You'll want to switch to [@Before and @After methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10806345/1426891) or [a Mockito JUnit4 rule](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/junit/MockitoRule.html) for your setup, if you use them both.

As an example, compressed from [a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40793464/1426891) that explains more about Parameterized runners versus JUnit rules and lifting from the [JUnit4 Parameterized Test](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests) doc page and [MockitoRule](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.22/org/mockito/junit/MockitoRule.html) doc page:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class YourComponentTest {
    @Rule public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
    @Mock YourDep mockYourDep;

    @Parameters public static Collection<Object[]> data() { /* Return the values */ }

    public YourComponentTest(Parameter parameter) { /* Save the parameter to a field */ }

    @Test public void test() { /* Use the field value in assertions */ }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this is the definitive answer.  But would you care to comment on the possibility at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745691/how-to-combine-runwith-with-runwithparameterized-class/27750897#comment68773212_27750897) of combining `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` with another `@RunWith`.  I tried to understand how to use this technique with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`, but it was beyond me (see my comments there).  I have doubts in view of what you say, but I thought I'd ask...

Comment: @mike Yes, you could create a parameterized Mockito runner using that technique, but while that post may be particularly useful for classloader-manipulating runners or runners that use dynamic tests, it is purely overkill in almost all Mockito situations because a `@Rule` would achieve this in a more modern idiomatic way. (MockitoJUnitRunner predates JUnit Rules.) If you want to see about combining them, it'd go better in another question—it wouldn't fit in a comment box and is no good general answer to either question.

Comment: Thanks.  You mean start a new question to ask for an explicit example of using @Rule?  I have now done this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40793464/parameterized-testing-with-mockito-by-using-junit-rule.  Hope you have a moment...

Answer (score 13):

If you are stuck with an older version of mockito where `MockitoRule` isn't available, the other possibility is to initialize the mocks explicitely with `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks`:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class YourComponentTest {        
    @Mock YourDep mockYourDep;

    @Parameter
    public Parameter parameter;

    @Parameters public static Collection<Object[]> data() { /* Return the values */ }

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test public void test() { /* Use the field value in assertions */ }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the JUnitParamsRunner. Here's how I do it:

```
import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import junitparams.Parameters;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;

@RunWith(value = JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ParameterizedMockitoTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SomeService someService;
    @Mock
    private SomeOtherService someOtherService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "getParameters")
    public void testWithParameters(Boolean parameter, Boolean expected) throws Exception {
        when(someOtherService.getSomething()).thenReturn(new Something());
        Boolean testObject = someService.getTestObject(parameter);
        assertThat(testObject, is(expected));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeBasicStuffWithoutParameters() {
        int i = 0;
        assertThat(i, is(0));
    }

    public Iterable getParameters() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.TRUE},
                {Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE},
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one note. This getParameters method does not have to be a public method.

Comment: correct, and with junit5 the teat methods dont have to be public anymore.

Comment: Here is how to import it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39366130/2518705

Answer (score 2):

What solved it for me was:

1. Class level annotation of `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`
2. Annotate each mock object with `@Mock`
3. `@InjectMocks` on the test class. Or a setup method annotated with `@BeforeEach` where you initialise the class to be tested.
4. if you need the @test annotation, make sure you import `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`. `org.junit.test` will not work!

I'm using mockito version 4.