# Parameterized tests that use a custom test runner

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, parameterized, parameterized-unit-test

We are using our custom test runner, that extend [ParentRunner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/ParentRunner.html):

```
public class OurTestRunner extends ParentRunner<TestRunnerForOneConfigCase> {...}

class TestRunnerForOneConfigCase extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {...}
```

Inspired by [how to combine @RunWith with @RunWith(Parameterized.class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745691/how-to-combine-runwith-with-runwithparameterized-class), I would like to use `OurTestRunner` with test parameters. So I am trying to implement the factory:

```
public class OurTestRunnerFactory implements ParametersRunnerFactory {
  @Override
  public org.junit.runner.Runner createRunnerForTestWithParameters(TestWithParameters test) throws InitializationError {
    return new OurTestRunner(test /* but it takes Class<T> as parameter */); 
  }
}
```

However, `OurTestRunner` and the its parent class `ParentRunner` take only the `Class<T>` as parameter, and not `TestWithParameters` (i.e. it doesn't take the parameters).

Is there a version of `ParentRunner` that is compatible with `Parameterized`? If not, what is the easiest way to extend our setup (without rewriting everything)?

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one Test Runner, but you can do it in such way:

```
 public class SimpleExampleTest {

    @Rule
    public Generator<String> params =
        new ListGenerator(asList("alpha", "beta", "gamma"));

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(params.value().length() >= 4);
    }
}
```