# How to import JunitParamsRunner in Java class

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

it is my first day with JUnit. I try to make test with parameters. I have code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class MoneyParameterizedTest {
    private static final Object[] getMoney() {
        return new Object[] {
                new Object[] {10, "USD"},
                new Object[] {20, "EUR"}
        };
    }
    @Test
    @Parameterized.Parameters(method = "getMoney")
    public void constructorShouldSetAmountAndCurrency(
            int amount, String currency) {
        Money money = new Money(amount, currency);
        assertEquals(amount, money.getAmount());
        assertEquals(currency, money.getCurrency());
    }
}
```

IntelliJ told me that: Can't resolve symbol JUnitParamsRunner and method. Is it problem with import? My class which I'm testing is in the same package.

----- **EDIT** -------

I change JunitParamsrunner.class to Parameterized.class and it's okay but problem with symbol 'method' in Parametrized.Parameters is the same.

Answer (score 6):

[`JUnitParams`](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams) ([licensed Apache 2.0](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/master/LICENSE.txt)) is a separate library, which means it's not shipped with JUnit itself. This also means that you need to make sure it's in the classpath of your project. If you're using maven (or something similar) then it's rather easy, you just need to add it as a dependency in your pom and make sure IJ has picked up the changes (wither automatically or manually if it shows a pop-up in the upper right corner):

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
  <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, [download it yourself](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/pl.pragmatists/JUnitParams/1.0.5) (click the `Download ( JAR )` link) and the [library](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/library.html) it to your classpath.

Please note that, although the concepts are similar, [`Parameterized`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests) is not the same thing with `JUnitParams`, the latter trying to simplify and improve the way you can write parametrized JUnit tests.

**P.S.:** There's another library called [`Zohhak`](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak) which seems even more flexible than `JUnitParams` but it's released under [`LGPL 3.0`](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak/blob/master/LICENSE-LGPL-3.0.txt) so it depends on your license restrictions.

Comment: could you tell me that is the same download for Maven and 'Classic' Java project? The same JAR?

Comment: @J.Carrer It's the same jar, but the difference being that maven (gradle, etc) does stuff automatically, making your life easier, for dependencies, build, etc

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that should work:

```
import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
//import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import junitparams.Parameters;

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class MoneyTest {

    private final static int VALID_AMOUNT = 5;
    private final static String VALID_CURRENCY = "USD";

    private static final Object[] getInvalidAmount() {
        return new Integer[][] {{-12387}, {-5}, {-1}};
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    @Parameters(method = "getInvalidAmount")
    public void constructorShouldThrowIAEForInvalidAmount(int invalidAmount){
        new Money(invalidAmount, VALID_CURRENCY);
    }

    private static final Object[] getInvalidCurrency(){
        return new String[][]{{null}, {""}};
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    @Parameters(method = "getInvalidCurrency")
    public void constructorShouldThrowIAEForInvalidCurrency(String invalidCurrency){
        new Money(VALID_AMOUNT, invalidCurrency);
    }

    private static final Object[] getMoney() {
        return new Object[] {
                new Object[] {10, "USD"},
                new Object[] {20, "EUR"}
        };
    }
    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "getMoney")
    public void constructorShouldSetAmountAndCurrency(
            int amount, String currency) {
        Money money = new Money(amount, currency);
        assertEquals(amount, money.getAmount());
        assertEquals(currency, money.getCurrency());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your POM.xml should like this ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>JUnit</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
        <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
        <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: test scope should be enough here, no need to specify the dependency second time with "compile" scope