# @InjectMocks and non-mocked objects (Spring Data Repositories)

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, spring-data

Is there any way to inject non-mocked objects with `@InjectMocks`?

My Setup has a `UserSignupService` with dependencies to a `MailService` and a `UserRepository` (a Spring Data Repository). I've a unit test creating a spy of the `MailService` and I annotated the `UserSignupService` with `@InjectMocks`. Sadly this won't inject the `UserRepository` (non-mocked) into the service class.
Combining `@InjectMocks` with `@Autowired` won't inject the mocked `MailService`, but the bean from the application context.

`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()` is run in `AbstractServiceTest.setUp()`. This class also holds the configuration of the the unit test (`SpringJunit4TestRunner`, etc.)

```
public class UserSignupServiceTest extends AbstractServiceTest {

  @Autowired @Spy
  private MailService<UserActivationMail> mailService;

  @InjectMocks
  private UserSignupServiceImpl service;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
  }
}

@Service
public class UserSignupServiceImpl implements UserSignupService {

  private final UserRepository repository;
  private final MailService<UserActivationMail> mailService;

  @Autowired
  public UserSignupServiceImpl(UserRepository repository,
                               MailService<UserActivationMail> mailService) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.mailService = mailService;
  }
  //methods...
}
```

Comment: did you try having a field in the test class for UserRepository with Autowired and Spy annotations ?

Comment: Yes, this worked actually, but I don't want to declare every dependency in the test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your Mockito  `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

Here is sample Spring JUnit test class I have

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:config/spring-context.xml" })
public class SpringKPTest {

    @Autowired
    SomeClassA SomeClassA;

    @Mock
    SomeClassB SomeClassB;



    @Before
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually if you have '@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)' annotation you don't have to add MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); initialzation to your code, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806345/runwithmockitojunitrunner-class-vs-mockitoannotations-initmocksthis

Comment: As mentioned, I already did that. The basic setup is fine and works how it should. The MailService is being spied by Mockito. It's about how to get non-mocked object from the application context to be injected with @InjectMocks.