# Mockito ArgumentCaptor gives NullpointerException on verify()

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, junit, mockito

I'm currently trying to create tests for our Servlets. I've mocked `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse` and an object serving as a database handler. In the test for the `doPost` method, my wish is to compare the values from the Json object and the ArrayList sent to the database object.

The servlet:

```
public class WidgetStatusServlet extends HttpServlet {

private DBController db = new DBController();

    @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement tradeElement = parser.parse(request.getParameter("widgetdata"));
    JsonArray json = tradeElement.getAsJsonArray();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<WidgetStatus>>() {
    }.getType();
    ArrayList<WidgetStatus> widgets = gson.fromJson(json, listType);

    Iterator<WidgetStatus> iterator = widgets.iterator();
    System.out.println("Widgets");
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        WidgetStatus node = (WidgetStatus) iterator.next();
        System.out.println(node);
    }

    db.addWidgetStatus(widgets);

}
```

The test:

```
public class WidgetStatusServletTest {

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<WidgetStatus>> captor;

private DBController dbMock = mock(DBController.class);
private HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
private HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
Repository repository = mock(Repository.class);`


    @Test
public void doPost_ShouldVerifyWidgetsIsProvided() throws Exception {
    final WidgetStatus widget1 = new WidgetStatus("id1", "div_id1", "5", "5", "1", "2", false);
    final WidgetStatus widget2 = new WidgetStatus("id2", "div_id2", "2", "1", "3", "1", true);

    when(request.getParameter("widgetdata")).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
        @Override
        public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            ArrayList<WidgetStatus> array = new ArrayList<WidgetStatus>();
            array.add(widget1);
            array.add(widget2);
            String json = new Gson().toJson(array);
            return json;
        }
    });
    new WidgetStatusServlet().doPost(request, response);
    verify(dbMock).addWidgetStatus(captor.capture());
    assertNotNull(captor.getAllValues());


}
```

When I'm running the test it gives me `NullpointerException` at the line

```
        verify(dbMock).addWidgetStatus(captor.capture());
```

What am I doing wrong? I've looked at several examples with the same usage of the `ArgumentCaptor`. Perhaps this is just a minor error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use the `MockitoJUnitRunner` to run your test, then an `ArgumentCaptor` will be created for you, and there's no need to initialise it explicitly.  If you do that, then you can also use the `@Mock` annotation to create your mock objects, that is, you don't need the `mock` static method any more.  Your test class would then begin like this.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class WidgetStatusServletTest {

    @Captor private ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<WidgetStatus>> captor;
    @Mock private DBController mockController;
    @Mock private HttpServletRequest mockRequest;
    @Mock private HttpServletResponse mockResponse;
    @Mock private Repository mockRepository;
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10806345/1081110) addresses the issue of whether to use `MockitoJUnitRunner`, or an explicit call to `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks`.

Just a side note - your test methods will be much easier to read if you use variable names that clearly indicate that your objects are mocks, like I've done here.  Otherwise, in a long test class with many different variables, it's easy to lose track of which variables reference mocks, and which reference "real" objects.

Comment: OK so now i got the following failure at the same line:  Wanted but not invoked:
mockController.addWidgetStatus(
    <Capturing argument>
);
-> at com.mycompany.bachelorprosjekt2014.servlets.WidgetStatusServletTest.doPost_ShouldVerifyWidgetsIsProvided(WidgetStatusServletTest.java:70)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Comment: Your problem is that your `WidgetStatusServlet` has its own `DBController` that is different from the mock one that you create.  If you want this test to work, you'll need to provide a way to inject your mock `DBController` into the `WidgetStatusServlet`.

Comment: I think i understand. So you're saying that i have to inject the mockController into the servlet before calling the doPost()?

Answer (score 6):

Fields marked with annotations `@Mock` and `@Captor` (and also `@Spy` and `@InjectMocks`) will be initialized automatically by Mockito, but only if you call [`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html) in the test class.

You can do this yourself in `setUp` (JUnit3) or a `@Before` method (JUnit4), or annotate your test case with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` to get automatic initialization and valiidation.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the `ArgumentCaptor` is not getting initialized.

When using mockito annotations, they are initialized by either

- Adding the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` line in the
  setup method

  ```
   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {

       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }
  ```
- Or by adding `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` annotation to the TestClass.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Junit 5 jupitor and the annotations like @Spy @Captor and @Mock is not working for you then it is because the "RunWith" was removed, you now need to use the Extensions using the "@ExtendWith" Annotation.

So, using `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` instead of `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` will do the trick for you and the annotations will work as they are supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize your `captor` object, therefore you cannot execute its `capture()` method. You must initialize an object before you are calling its methods.