# How to inject or replace a @Resource dependency?

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, mocking, ejb

I have SomeService that uses a @Resource annotation for EJB TimerService.

@Resource
private TimerService timerService;

How can I inject a mock TimerService in place of this TimerService in SomeService?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using mockito: Mockito can inject annotated fields for you see: 
[@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) vs MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806345/runwithmockitojunitrunner-class-vs-mockitoannotations-initmocksthis)

I would suggest instead of using annotations on fields to use a annotated constructor. That way you can make all injected fields final and you will get build failures when dependencies change instead of runtime/test failures/exceptions. And the added bonus is that you can just call the constructor in your tests and inject the mocks that way.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are describing with an annotated constructor?

Comment: @user840930 https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/injection.html