# Mocking chained method calls in AndroidAnnotations SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, android-annotations

In a project I am using [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/) to generate [SharedPreferences](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/SharedPreferencesHelpers):

```
import org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.DefaultBoolean;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.SharedPref;

@SharedPref(value = SharedPref.Scope.UNIQUE)
public interface MySharedPreferences {

    @DefaultBoolean(false)
    boolean enabled();
}
```

The generated class can be used as follows:

```
preferences.enabled().get();
preferences.enabled().put(true);
```

I am trying to write a unit test which checks some logic. There I want to mock the preferences:

```
@Mock MyPreferences_ prefs;
MyLogic logic;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    logic = new Logic();
}

@Test
public void testEnabled() throws Exception {
    when(prefs.enabled().get()).thenReturn(false);
    assertThat(logic.isEnabled()).isEqualTo(false);
}
```

However, accessing `prefs.enabled()` throws a `NullPointerException`:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.example.MyLogicTest.isValuesStoredProperly(MyLogicTest.java) ...

Is it possible to mock a chained method call (including null objects) with Mockito?

## Update

As an update based on the [helpful suggestions by alayor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44050752/356895) I changed my implementation as follows:

```
public class MyLogicTest {

    @Mock SharedPreferences        prefs;
    @Mock CustomSharedPreferences_ prefs_;

    MyLogic logic;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        logic = new MyLogic();
    }

    @Test
    public void testEnabled() throws Exception {
        MockPrefs mockPrefs = new MockPrefs(prefs);
        when(prefs_.enabled()).thenReturn(mockPrefs.getEnabledPrefField());
        doNothing().when(prefs_.enabled()).put(anyBoolean()); // <-- fails
        when(prefs_.enabled().get()).thenReturn(false);
        assertThat(logic.isEnabled()).isEqualTo(false);
    }

    private class MockPrefs extends SharedPreferencesHelper {

        public MockPrefs(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
            super(sharedPreferences);
        }

        public BooleanPrefField getEnabledPrefField() {
            return super.booleanField("enabled", enabledOld);
        }

    }
}
```

This still **fails** here:

```
doNothing().when(prefs_.enabled()).put(anyBoolean());
```

The `BooleanPrefField` object from `prefs_.enabled()` is `final` and cannot be mocked.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at MyLogicTest.testEnabled

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

## Sample project

- [Simplified sample project](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/EnabledTest)

## Solution

- Please find the working in above sample project.

Comment: What does `prefs.enabled()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to mock the chained method call you could use this annotation in `MyPreferences_`

`@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)`.

But I recommend that you mock the result of calling `prefs.enabled()` instead.

```
@Mock 
BooleanPrefField booleanPrefField;

@Test
public void testEnabled() throws Exception {
    when(prefs.enabled()).thenReturn(booleanPrefField);
    when(booleanPrefField.get()).thenReturn(false);
    assertThat(logic.isEnabled()).isEqualTo(false);
}
```

Note: You should substitute `MyObject` with the type of object that `prefs.enabled()` returns. Using this way you have more control over the behavior of your method calls.

UPDATE: In case `BooleanPrefField` is final, you could simply return an object of that class in your mocking.

```
when(prefs.enabled()).thenReturn(SharedPreferencesHelper.booleanField("", false));
```

Comment: I tried that but `BooleanPrefField` is `final`. Error: `Cannot mock/spy class org.androidannotations.api.sharedpreferences.BooleanPrefField Mockito cannot mock/spy because: final class`

Comment: And `BooleanPrefField` is package private which prevents me from instantiating a new object such as `new BooleanPrefField(true)`.

Comment: You can try to use `SharedPreferencesHelper.booleanField("", false)`

Comment: Please explain "... simply return an object of that class in your mocking ...". I could not see `SharedPreferencesHelper.booleanField` exists as a static method.

Comment: I see this class exists in `org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences` package. There must be a way to create a `BooleanPrefField` object.
http://javadox.com/org.androidannotations/androidannotations-api/3.2/org/androidannotations/api/sharedpreferences/SharedPreferencesHelper.html

Comment: Yes. I can extend from `SharedPreferencesHelper` and implement a method such as `public BooleanPrefField enabledPrefField() { return super.booleanField("enabled", false); }` but which `SharedPreferences` object do I pass to the constructor? It is invoked inside `BooleanPrefField.getOr()` as in `sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);`.

Comment: You could pass a mocked `SharedPreferences` object.

Comment: I updated my question with the current implementation. However, when persisting the value via `put` mocking fails again due to the `final` restriction of `BooleanPrefField`.

Comment: I created a simplified sample project [here](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/EnabledTest).

Comment: Thanks for you input - I finally were able to mock `final` classes by using `mockito-inline`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your tests with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` instead of `MockitoAnnotations`? The runner should initialize all `@Mock` annotated fields automatically and get rid of that NPE.

Also maybe following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10812752/1744230) could help you further.

Comment: The `prefs` object is initialized. That is not the problem. The NPE occurs when I invoke `.get` on `prefs.enabled()` which returns a `BooleanPrefField` in the implementation case.