# Unable to mock object of class residing in different project

Tags: java, mockito

This is how I am mocking object of class `Client` present in another project:

```
@Mock
private Client client;

//Mocking method of class client - 

@Test
public void test()
{
    Mockito.when(client.getPassportDetail(Matchers.eq(bytes),Matchers.eq(properties)))
           .thenReturn(hash);
}
```

Structure of class Client:

```
class Client
{

    public static boolean loadLibraries(Properties properties) {
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getPassportDetail(byte[] b, Properties properties) throws Exception{
        if (!loadLibraries(properties)) 
        {
            throw new UnsatisfiedLinkError();
        }
    }
```

So, when I mock `getPassportDetail` method, it gets called, not mocked.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Your input is simply incomplete. Is it correct that the *Client* class is **not** public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a common mistake. Actually @Mock annotation need something more to work as You want to.

You have 3 options there:

Add

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

to Your test class.

Or

```
@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

There is also 3rd option, that [@Dawood ibn Kareem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081110/dawood-ibn-kareem) suggest in comment below:

> There's a third option, which is better than either of these two. Use the new Mockito Rule - @Rule public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();. More detail at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10812752), which also explains why this is the best of the three options.

That should be all.

You can always refer to http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations for more informations and detailed explanation.

Comment: There's a third option, which is better than either of these two.  Use the new Mockito Rule - `@Rule public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();`.  More detail at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10812752),  which also explains why this is the best of the three options.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem wow, I didn't know about it. Thanks for advice! :)