# Spring boot mocked object returning null on call

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I am using `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` to writing unit test case to mock the object. I am trying to mock the repository instance which is accepting request object and returning response, but in unit test case implementation I have mocked the repository using `@MockBean` annotation and register the it's method call using `Mockito.when(respository.post(request)).thenReturn(response)`. But this call is returning `null`.

Comment: Try @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class), or if you need to use SpringRunner, initialise your mocks -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806345/runwithmockitojunitrunner-class-vs-mockitoannotations-initmocksthis

Comment: Have you added `@SpringBootTest` to your test?

Comment: @tgdavies Agreed but that's a completely different story. I am sure `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` will work.

@Luay - @SpringBootTest is not working either.

Answer (score 6):

I faced similar situation, the problem is given parameter in `Mockito.when()` block may not be the same as spring generated. I'll explain my case below, hope to help you:

```java
Product product = new Product(..);
Mockito.when(service.addProduct(product)).thenReturn(saveProduct)
```

When I send a request, spring generates new Project object which has same fields with `product` but instance is different. That is, Mockito cannot catch `when` statement. I changed it like below and it's worked:

```java
Mockito.when(service.addProduct(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(savedProduct)
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. But the solution is still weird to me...

I was facing this issue because, I was instantiating the `request` and `response` in `@Before` annotated method... as describing below.

```
    @Before
public void setup() {
    Request reqA = new Request();
    reqA.set..(..);

    Response res = new Response();
    res.set..(..);

    Mockito.when(this.respository.post(reqA)).thenReturn(res);
}

@Test
public void test() {

    // Creating Request instance again with all same properties. 
    // Such that this req instance is technically similarly as instantiated in @Before annotated method (above). 
    // By, implementing the equals and hashCode method.
    Request reqB = new Request();
    reqB.set..(..);

    // Getting res as 'null' here....
    Response res = this.service.post(reqB);
}
```

Since, `reqA` and `reqB` are technically similar then why mocked call not returning the same response as registered.

If I moved `setup()` method code inside `test()` method every thing starts working !!!!!

Comment: If `Request` does not implement equals in a way that `reqA.equals( actualRequest )` returns `true`, then Mockito will not know that this "`actualRequest`" is the one you are looking for. By moving it into the test method, I assume you are then using `reqA` as the actual request, which of course works, since `reqA == reqA`, allowing Mockito to realize that this is the one you are waiting for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here, vsk.rahul's comment helped me a lot.
I was trying to to use a method to return a mock interaction, but not succeeded, turning it into a **static method** gave me the expected behavior.

**Problem**:
The method `bar.foo()` was returning `null` for any interaction

```
public void test1() {
    doReturn(mockReturn()).when(bar).foo();
}

private String mockReturn() {
    return "abc";
}
```

**Solution**:
The method `bar.foo()` is returning `abc` String for any interaction

```
public void test1() {
    doReturn(mockReturn()).when(bar).foo();
}

private static String mockReturn() {
    return "abc";
}
```