# Use Mocked object in JUnit / Mockito test

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have a JUnit test that reads

```
public class  EventHandlerTest  {

    @Mock
    ThreadPoolExtendedExecutor threadPoolExtendedExecutor;

    private EventHandler handler;
    private Map<Queue<SenderTask>> subBuffers = new HashMap<>();


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // PROBLEM: threadPoolExtendedExecutor null!
        handler = new EventHandler(subBuffers, threadPoolExtendedExecutor);
    }


}
```

When I call new in setUp, I have `threadPoolExtendedExecutor=null`.
I would like to insert some mocked `threadPoolExtendedExecutor` so, I do not have `NullPointer` problems when calling its methods (so simple interface mock is enough for me at this moment)

Comment: You could do it with ThreadPoolExtendedExecutor threadPoolExtendedExecutor = mock(ThreadPoolExtendedExecutor .class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply mock it using (in setUp)

threadPoolExtendedExecutor = mock(ThreadPoolExtendedExecutor.class);

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    threadPoolExtendedExecutor = mock(ThreadPoolExtendedExecutor.class);
    handler = new EventHandler(subBuffers, threadPoolExtendedExecutor);
}
```

You can also let MockitoJUnitRunner do it for you :
don't forget to inject mocks in your service under test by annotating it with @InjectMocks

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class  EventHandlerTest  {

    @Mock
    ThreadPoolExtendedExecutor threadPoolExtendedExecutor;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use the `@Mock` or `@InjectMocks` annotations on the test class fields then you need to add `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` at the class level.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class  EventHandlerTest  {

    @Mock
    ThreadPoolExtendedExecutor threadPoolExtendedExecutor;
```

Another approach is to not use the above annotations and manually create mocks by calling `org.mockito.Mockito.mock()`.

Comment: Also have a look at @InjectMocks which would inject mocked object into your unit test class for you so that you don't have to call constructor explicitly.

Comment: A couple of other options are [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10806345)

Comment: @Rakesh No that's not really what InjectMocks does.