# Argument passed to verify() is of type Attendee and is not a mock! Error

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

So I have this mockito test that basicaly tests that attendees are recivint their notifications

@Mock
Event event;

```
  @Mock
    Attendee attende;

    @InjectMocks
    EventNotificationServiceImpl eventNotificationService;

    @Test
    public void checkIfAtendesAreNotified(){
        Event event = new Event();
         Attendee attende = new Attendee(1L,"sara","sara@example.com");

        event.addAttendee(attende);
        eventNotificationService.announce(event);

        List <Notification> notifications = attende.getNotifications();

        for (Notification notification : notifications) {
            assertEquals("The next big event is coming!",notification.getMessage());

    }
        verify( attende, times(1)).getNotifications();
    }
}
```

Id like to add some verify method but i get the org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException:
**Argument passed to verify() is of type Attendee and is not a mock!**

Anyone have some idea why??? i tried different combinations but always get same error.

thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: How are you initialising your mocks?  With `initMocks`?  With the JUnit rule?  or with the `MockitoJUnitRunner`?  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/10806345/

Comment: No but teacher doesnt showed us anything about initMocks??? so not sure i should put it ???

Comment: OK I've added a link to my previous comment, where someone asked a similar question.  It might be helpful to you.

Comment: You shadowed your mock with a local variable 'attende' which is not a mock.

Comment: Ooh, well spotted @Januson.  That looks like it's the answer.